# Half-Normal Plot of Coefficients from Binary Factorial Experiments

Tags: self-study, logistic, model-selection, fractional-factorial

After I wrote this all up I debated whether or not I should post it because I think I know the answer to this question (after looking at the two models I'd end up with), but since I don't really know or understand the why here you go...

Can (or maybe should) half-normal probability plotting to determine significance of effects in unreplicated $2^k$ and $2^{k-p}$ factorial and fractional factorial designs be extended to experiments where the response is binary?

Consider the following data set where *p* is the proportion of successes out of 1,000 trials. (This data set is from the article *Analysis of Factorial Experiments with Defects or Defectives as the Response* by Bisgaard and Fuller. If I can't find the answer in other readings, at some point I'll post another question as to why they chose the regression approach they did over using logistic regression.)

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  J  K     p weights
-1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 0.958    1000
 1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 1.000    1000
-1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 0.977    1000
 1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 0.775    1000
-1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 0.958    1000
 1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 0.958    1000
-1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 0.813    1000
 1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 0.906    1000
-1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 0.679    1000
 1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 0.781    1000
-1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 1.000    1000
 1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 0.896    1000
-1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 0.958    1000
 1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 0.818    1000
-1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 0.841    1000
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.955    1000
```

Would using a half-normal probability plot be a valid way of determining the significant terms from a logistic regression approach to the data set?

Below is my half-normal probability plot function for `R`.

```
#####################################################################################
half.norm<-function(abs.coefs=abs.coef.dist[-1], main="Distance"){                  #
    (n<-length(abs.coefs))                                                          #
    i<-1:n                                                                          #
    (Actual<-.5*(((i-.5)/n)+1))                                                     #
    (Expected<-qnorm(Actual))                                                       #
    abscoefs2<-c(abs.coefs, -abs.coefs)                                             #
    par(pty="s")    #square plotting region                                         #
    plot(x=Expected, y=sort(abs.coefs), ylab="abs(coef)", main=main)                #
    qqline(abscoefs2,col=3, lwd=2)                                                  #
    output<-list(Expected,sort(abs.coefs))                                          #
    names(output)<-c("Expected","abs.coefs")                                        #
    return(output)                                                                  #
}                                                                                   #
                                                                                    #
cat('Example:\nhalf.norm(abs.coefs = abs(coef(model)[-1]), main = "Distance")\n\n', #
'When extracting the model coef() the intercept is the first coef.\n',              #
'The intercept needs to be removed, that is why the [-1] is used.\n'                #
)                                                                                   #
#####################################################################################
```

Here is my code for creating the logit model and the resulting half-normal probability plot.

```
logistic<-glm(p ~ A*B*C*D*E*F*G*H*J*K, family=binomial(logit), weights=weights, data=data)


#Half-Normal Probability Plot of Factor Effects
windows(4,4)
par(mar=c(3,2.5,2,.5), mgp=c(1.7,.4,0), las=1, tck=-.01,
    cex.lab=.8, cex.axis=.8, cex.main=.9)

a<-half.norm(abs.coefs = sort(abs(coef(logistic)[-1]), decreasing=T), 
   main = "Half-Normal Plot of Factor Coefs\nProportion Non-Defectives")
keep<-7
points(x=rev(a$Expected)[1:keep], y=rev(a$abs.coefs)[1:keep], col="red", pch=16)
text(x=rev(a$Expected)[1:keep], y=rev(a$abs.coefs)[1:keep], 
    labels=names(rev(a$abs.coefs)[1:keep]), col="red", pos=1, cex=.7)
```

[image]

Or would that approach not be sound and we would want to reduce the model based on p-values such as looking at the results from `anova.glm(logistic, test="Chisq")`?